# Yii 1.1 with PHP 5.6: how to skip Redis connection error silently

Tags: php, exception, yii, redis

I am reading some extra information from Redis and the desired behaviour is to skip connection error silently, if any:

```
try {
    $r = new Redis();
    $r->connect("127.0.0.1", "6379");
} catch (Error $e) {
    ;
} catch (Throwable $e) {
    ;
}
```

If Redis fails, monitoring system will show alert to right people to fix it.

Unfortunatelly the code above still causes Yii to fail and produce HTTP 500:

```
2018/04/09 12:28:04 [error] [php] Redis::connect(): connect() failed: Connection refused
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no such command connect in yii2 redis

Comment: @Ofershap, does this also apply to yii 1.1, which OP is specifically asking about?

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the `Exception` thrown...

```
try {
    $r = new Redis();
    $r->connect("127.0.0.1", "6379");
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    ;
}
```

I think you can catch the very specific exception of `Predis\Connection\ConnectionException` if you need to.